# EaselJS cache Text object

Tags: caching, rendering, easeljs, createjs

I would like some help regarding caching Text objects using EaselJS library.

I never fully understood how caching works, and i must be missing something really fundamental, because i cannot seem to make it work.

Take the following simle example.

```
this.label.cache(this.label.x, this.label.y, rec.width, rec.height);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xnqcjsg8/

If you comment the line that caches the Text object then it is displayed correctly. Otherwise you can see nothing on stage.

I know that i can and should cache text objects, because they are expensive to render, but i cannot figure out how.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caching is relative to the object, so if you move the object on the x/y, you don't have to update the cache. Additionally, when you adjust the alignment, the bounds will have an `x` and `y` property, which will be the offset of the top left from the registration point.

Here is an update fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/xnqcjsg8/1/

This is the new cache function. If you sub out the x and y with `[0,0]` you can see that how it crops based on the alignment.

```
this.label.cache(rec.x, rec.y, rec.width, rec.height);
```

I also simplified your fiddle a little.

Comment: That makes sense now! Thanks a lot. Would you mind answering another related question right here, so i wouldn't have to create a new one? I am not sure if i'm going over the rules here....

Comment: Happy to help if I can.

Comment: Would it help if i cached a container with many bitmaps in it? I read somewhere (not sure if accurate), that caching should be avoided in Bitmap objects, and only be used in Shapes/Text and vector graphics in general. Thanks again!

Comment: Caching a single Bitmap is unnecessary (except if you want to use filters, then it's mandatory), since the cache just makes a "copy" of the Bitmap in the background (in a canvas instance) and draws it instead. I have heard of cases where it seems to improve performance, but I have not seen that personally.   If you are putting a bunch of images together in a Container, and they won't change, then caching that container can give you a big performance boost, since it will reduce the draw calls to just the one container cache. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will definetly try it.